# VBA function fails when i have a shape selected in the sheet, but not otherwise

Tags: excel, vba

Why does this happen?

I have a cell in my sheet that i programmatically set the validation contents, it lists all the files in a directory.

The problem is, that this can get to be longer than 255 characters (i set it using the `aaa,bbb,ccc` method) limit, which works, but when you then open the sheet you get an error and excel with tell you it needs to repair the sheet, and will remove the validation from the cells.

So i have a function to remove the validation before saving the file.

It works.

Now the problem, when i have a button selected, like this:

[image]

and i then try to save, i get an error. Here's the code:

```
With Sheets("SomeSheet").Range("SomeRange").Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertInformation, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=files
    .InputTitle = "Files"
    .ErrorTitle = "File not found"
    .ErrorMessage = "File does not exist."
End With
```

where i get the error on the `.Add Type:=...` line:

[image]

What is also strange, is that i actually have two ranges i'm clearing, one in a different sheet, and one in the same sheet as the shape. The one in the other sheet does not fail.

If i place a shape in a different sheet, select that, and then run the vba, it does not fail.

If i select the shape, change sheet, the run the vba, it does not fail (if you then change back to the original shape the shape is still selected, but this might just be because excel is remembering the state).

I get the same behaviour with buttons, and also with objects like graphs.

What is going on?

Comment: Just wondering if you could divide the filenames into a range of cells instead of putting them all into a single cell.  It sounds like you're going to have difficulty with the 255 character limit whichever way you go.

Comment: Sure, i could do that, now i have to have some random extra sheet in the workbook holding a range of file names - i don't want to do this, and I'd like to know what's actually causing this problem.

Comment: You can workaround the issue if you select a cell like `.Cells(1,1).Select` I think. • Side Note: I recommend always using `Worksheets` instead of `Sheets`. The `Sheets` collection can contain Chart or Worksheet objects. The `Worksheets` collection contains only Worksheet objects. So never use `Sheets` unless you need to include Charts etc. Because `Sheets("SomeSheet").Range` will fail on a Chart object.

Comment: What is the purpose of the shape?  Does clicking it run a macro?  How does the cell with all the file names get populated?

Comment: the shape runs a macro yes, but it's a different macro, and i get the same behaviour if i create a chart, or a button, or another shape, and they don't need to have macros assigned to them to cause this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

So i fixed the issue,

```
Dim originalSelection As Object
Set originalSelection = Selection
Range("A1").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False

...

originalSelection.Select
```

I feel this is better than other workarounds, as it leaves the state of the workbook unchanged, and it works with arbitrary selections (i.e. a random line in a chart, etc.)

I would still like to know why it actually happens though.

Comment: It was due to the exceeded limit of 255 characters of your conglomerated cell content.  I still suggest to divvy them up into the last 5 to 10 rows of your current worksheet (to prevent the need for adding some other random worksheet) and conglomerate them and de-conglomerate them into and out of the single cell when needed.